# Initializing a class template's member based on different conditions

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17, list-initialization

I have a class template that has two constructors, one takes a unsigned type and the other takes a constant reference of its self, both constructors have the same behavior in how it constructs the class.

There are 3 cases in how this class can be constructed and this is determined on the sizes of the type it is and the type being passed in. I also would like the members to be initialized by the class constructors' initializer lists.

The class looks something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T data;

    template<typename P>
    Foo( const P val, const unsigned char c ) :
    data { static_cast<T>( val /* some operation done to val based on each case*/ ) } {
        assert( /* based on cases above,
                and each case has its own conditions to assert */ ); 
    }

    template<typename P>
    Foo( const Foo<P>& f, const unsigned char c ) :
    data{ static_cast<T>( Foo.val /* some operation done to val based on each case*/ ) } {
        assert( /* based on cases above, 
                and each case has its own conditions to assert */ );
};
```

The 3 cases are as follows:

> ```
> case 1: if( sizeof(P) > sizeof(T) )
>            construct Foo<T> with these conditions,
>            initialize member data in this specific way
>            and assert accordingly
> case 2: if( sizeof(T) > sizeof(P) )
>            construct Foo<T> with these conditions,
>            initialize member data in this specific way
>            and assert accordingly
> case 3: if ( sizeof(T) == sizeof(P) )
>            construct Foo<T> with these conditions,
>            initialize member data in this specific way
>            and assert accordingly
> ```

Is there a simple way to do this? Remember that the member is being initialized via the constructors' initializer list, but the data member will be initialized in a different manner all depending on the 3 cases above.

I don't know how I would be able to approach this. All the information here should be available at compile time, so I don't see why there should be an issues, but I don't know how to setup the constructors to have this functionality. Furthermore can this even be done?

---

**EDIT**

A little bit of background on types `T` & `P`: both `T` & `P` are any of the following:

> Types:           Size in Bytes:    Size in bits:
>
> - `std::uint8_t`  1 byte            8 bits
> - `std::uint16_t` 2 bytes          16 bits
> - `std::uint32_t` 4 bytes          32 bits
> - `std::uint64_t` 8 bytes          64 bits

Once we have our 3 conditions defined based on the comparison of the two sizes, the assertions work as follows: the unsigned char passed in is also a part of the conditions within the assertions and it has a range of values that it can be. Here is a table for that: The unsigned char I'll represent with `idx`.

```
using u8  = std::uint8_t;
using u16 = std::uint16_t;
using u32 = std::uint32_t;
using u64 = std::uint64_t;

if ( sizeof(P) > sizeof(T) )
   // comparision formula:
   // idx <= (((sizeof(P) / sizeof(T)) - 1)
   // Foo<T = u8> From: Foo<P = u16> idx[0,1], Foo<P =u32> idx[0,3], Foo<P = u64> idx[0,7]
   // Foo<T = u16> From: Foo<P = u32> idx[0,1], Foo<P = u64> idx[0,3]
   // Foo<T = u32> From: Foo<P = u64> idx[0,1]

if ( sizeof(T) > sizeof(P) )
   // comparision formula:
   // idx <= (((sizeof(T) / sizeof(P)) - 1)
   // Foo<T = u16> From: Foo<P = u8> idx[0,1]
   // Foo<T = u32> From: Foo<P = u8> idx[0,4], Foo<P = u16> idx[0,1]
   // Foo<T = u64> From: Foo<P = u8> idx[0,7], Foo<P = u16> idx[0,3], Foo<P = u32> idx[0,1]

if ( sizeof(P) == sizeof(T) ) {
   // no conditional checks
   // no assertion
   // in this case idx is not used and is not a part of any calculation
   // the two sizes match so it's just a normal initialization.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a situation where `if constexpr` cannot be used and you have to fall back on SFINAE. First, delegate the construction from the `Foo<P>` constructor to the `P` constructor:

```
template<typename P>
Foo(const Foo<P>& f, const unsigned char c) : Foo(f.val, c) {}
```

The `P` constructor just needs to have three alternatives, exactly one of which is enabled depending on the size of `P`:

```
template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(P) > sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
Foo(P val, const unsigned char c) : data(...) {}

template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<sizeof(P) == sizeof(T)>* = nullptr>
Foo(P val, const unsigned char c) : data(...) {}

template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(P) < sizeof(T))>* = nullptr>
Foo(P val, const unsigned char c) : data(...) {}
```

You could also add an extra layer of delegation if you want the `P` constructor to have the same assertions regardless of the size of `P`.

Comment: I'll edit the question above on how the assertions work.

Comment: I finished with the edits to give more information on how the construction is to be performed.

Comment: However I think I'm starting to understand or see the pattern here with SFINAE and how `std::enable_if_t` is being used.

Comment: I created a dummy class to replicate what you have did above, and I'm getting a Visual Studio 2017 compiler error C2059: syntax error: `sizeof`

Comment: I think I have the shell of this completed now, I haven't done any testing. Once I test this in a simple case; I should be able to integrate it into my actual class.